# Why the output is not shown while using nested streamlit buttons?

Tags: python, streamlit

This is the streamlit code that I'm currently working on.
When I click the button "About Python" It is working fine and showing the "Generate Syntax" button. But then when I click on the "Generate Syntax" button it is not showing anything and my program is running from the first again.

```
left, center, right = st.beta_columns(3)

left_one = left.button("About Python", key="1")
center_one = center.button("Learn Python", key="2")
right_one = right.button("Practice Python", key="3")

if left_one:
    generate_syntax = st.button("Generate Syntax", key="4")
    if generate_syntax:
        st.write("Hello All..")
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This can be seen quite often in [Streamlit discussions](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/the-button-inside-a-button-seems-to-reset-the-whole-app-why/1051) because it looks like a bug at the first glance, but it's not. A simple and silly answer would be "That's the way streamlit is designed".
So every time you press the button, streamlit will re-run the whole web page and it doesn't remember the previous state(information in the previous button).

Although I never found any official answer on how to exactly solve this, I did manage to do some workarounds.

1. Using checkboxes rather than buttons
2. Using [Session State](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/is-there-any-working-example-for-session-state-for-streamlit-version-0-63-1/4551)
3. Creating small functions and calling them during your `if` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

When you click `About Python`:

- the value of `left_one` becomes `True`
- the value of all other buttons (including `generate_syntax`) becomes `False`

When you click `Generate Syntax`:

- the value of `generate_syntax` becomes `True`
- the value of `left_one` becomes `False`

The issue is that you never meet both conditions of `generate_syntax` being `True` AND `left one` being `True`. So you never print `"Hello All"` Streamlit only thinks of one statechange at a time when it comes to buttons.

The way to get around this is by using an object to store state. @pathe_rao has already suggesting using `SessionState` object from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tvst/036da038ab3e999a64497f42de966a92):

```py
import streamlit as st  

### Copy and Paste Session state code here

session_state = SessionState.get(left =False, right = False, center = False)
  
left, center, right = st.beta_columns(3)

left_one = left.button("About Python",key = "1")
center_one = center.button("Learn Python", key = "2")
right_one = right.button("Practice Python", key = "3")


if left_one or session_state.left:
    session_state.left  = True
    session_state.right = False
    session_state.center = False

    generate_syntax = st.button("Generate Syntax", key = "4")
    if generate_syntax:
        st.write("Hello All..")

if center_one or session_state.center:
    session_state.left  = False
    session_state.right = False
    session_state.center = True

if right_one or session_state.right:
    session_state.left  = False
    session_state.right = True
    session_state.center = False
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, two of your buttons aren't really wired into anything, so I'll just focus on a single nested button.

Unlike most other UI libraries, Streamlit isn't event-driven and instead works like Leonard Shelby from the film [Memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_(film)). In that movie, the protagonist repeatedly blacks out and forgets recent events. He uses tattoos to store information that should persist between amnesia blackouts.

Similarly, in Streamlit, triggered events cause the script to re-execute from the start, totally forgetting everything except `st.session_state`, which works like Leonard's tattoos to keep track of important information, like which menus are in an open state.

Here's one approach using state:

```py
import streamlit as st  # 1.18.1


def handle_about_python_open():
    state.about_python = True


def handle_generate_syntax_open():
    state.about_python = True


def close():
    state.about_python = False
    state.generate_syntax = False


state = st.session_state
state.about_python = state.get("about_python")
state.generate_syntax = state.get("generate_syntax")

if (
    st.button("About Python", on_click=handle_about_python_open) or
    state.about_python
):
    if (
        st.button("Generate Syntax", on_click=handle_generate_syntax_open)
        or state.generate_syntax
    ):
        st.write("Hello All..")

        # close the outer button, optionally
        st.button("Close", on_click=close)
```

Note that the `on_click` callback changes state but the condition version doesn't seem to:

```py
if st.button("Close"):
    state.about_python = False
```

If you want to generalize this, you can:

```py
def create_nested_button_col(i, col, text):
    with col:
        if st.button(text) or state.open[i][0]:
            state.open[i][0] = True

            if st.button(f"{text} inner") or state.open[i][1]:
                st.write(f"Hello {text}..")
                state.open[i][1] = True

                def handle_close():
                    state.open[i][0] = False
                    state.open[i][1] = False

                st.button(f"Close {text}", on_click=handle_close)


state = st.session_state
button_text = "foo", "bar", "baz"
state.open = state.get("open", [[False] * 2 for _ in range(len(button_text))])
pairs = zip(st.columns(len(button_text)), button_text)

for i, (col, text) in enumerate(pairs):
    create_nested_button_col(i, col, text)
```

From this, it should be clear that we can arbitrarily generalize with as many nested buttons as we want, as long as we keep state on open/closed state for each button. A 2d grid of booleans could do it.